# Trying to parse complex JSON from Instagram with AFNetworking. Driving me a bit crazy

Tags: ios, json, instagram, afnetworking-2

Parsing simple JSON with AFNetworking is well documented and seems very straight forward. What I'm trying to do is parse JSON from Instagram, which is many levels deep into an array where I can pull the images and insert into a CollectionView. Right now I'm stuck. My simple code returns everything in a single text block, and not what I need at all. What I'm trying to grab is outlined in Red. If I grab 10 images, I really want those all in an array. At that point I can grab the actually images and display them. Right now I'm stuck.

Find all images that are tagged Snow:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/snow/media/recent?access_token=836379.f59def8.fd07b9ba8ea440188dc56d2763bbf6c2

[image]

Code that just return a string of image names, which is not want I want at all.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

  NSLog(@">>> Entering %s <<<", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

  [super viewDidLoad];

  NSString *path = @"https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/snow/media/recent?access_token=836379.f59def8.fd07b9ba8ea440188dc56d2763bbf6c2";

  NSLog(@"path %@", path);

  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];

  AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
  [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                  success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

                                                    NSString *image = [[[[JSON valueForKey:@"data"]valueForKey:@"images"]valueForKey:@"low_resolution"]valueForKey:@"url"];

                                                    NSLog(@"%@", image);


                                                  } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON){
                                                    // NSLog(@"There was a problem: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                                  }];

  [operation start];

  //NSDictionary *dict = [imagesArry objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

This is what I get:

"http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/3bc4787a401f11e384ec22000ab5caf6_6.jpg",
    "http://distilleryimage3.s3.amazonaws.com/d32fb366401d11e3ba2d22000ae90e24_6.jpg",
    "http://distilleryimage4.s3.amazonaws.com/903d89f6401911e382a322000a1f9709_6.jpg",
    "http://distilleryimage6.s3.amazonaws.com/84350bf8401d11e393e722000aaa0a4a_6.jpg",
    "http://distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com/45387d48401f11e3b9ed22000a1f8cd8_6.jpg",
    "http://distilleryimage2.s3.amazonaws.com/350228c0401f11e3993b22000ae81198_6.jpg",
    "http://distilleryimage4.s3.amazonaws.com/6da0b634401e11e3977b22000aeb36ba_6.jpg",
    "http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/a0d357722b5c11e3988a22000a1fbac2_6.jpg",
    "http://distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com/b2a25ba8400e11e3bfd922000ae90db3_6.jpg",
    "http://distilleryimage2.s3.amazonaws.com/1f6c4716401f11e39bdd22000aeb0cb1_6.jpg",
    "http://distilleryimage0.s3.amazonaws.com/ca032f722c5711e38c7122000ab5c5fc_6.jpg",
    "http://distilleryimage2.s3.amazonaws.com/4ca448be3fde11e3b66b22000aa8003c_6.jpg",
    "http://distilleryimage2.s3.amazonaws.com/19fc276c401d11e3b22b22000a1f96e2_6.jpg",
    "http://distilleryimage6.s3.amazonaws.com/e36d5a202ddb11e3ac9b22000a1fb864_6.jpg",
    "http://distilleryimage3.s3.amazonaws.com/283e1266401f11e3bf9922000a1fbc1c_6.jpg",
    "http://distilleryimage4.s3.amazonaws.com/01e0ccc6401f11e3854822000ae90109_6.jpg",
    "http://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/b43573fa401e11e3942822000a1fbb05_6.jpg",
    "http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/f6029e5c401e11e3ab8622000ab5c723_6.jpg",
    "http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/6d914dde401e11e38c3f22000ae800af_6.jpg"
)

Just seems like I'm not approaching it right, is it that simple? One line get grab all my Instagram images links? Hmmmm, it does look like they are seperated by ",". Could it be that simple?

NSString *image = [[[[JSON valueForKey:@"data"]valueForKey:@"images"]valueForKey:@"low_resolution"]valueForKey:@"url"];

UPDATE:

Ok, almost. This is a bit strange, seems very straight forward, trying to split the array by "," yet i am sure I'm working on a string:

NSArray *listItems = [image componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

ERROR: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b84710'

Comment: So what do you want?  (If you want all elements in the data array seems to me you should ask for all elements.)

Comment: In fact, are you sure you're not getting all the elements?  What does "everything in a single text block" look like?  If it's  `( http:someurl, http:someurl... )` it's an array of all the URLs.

Comment: Ok, almost. This is a bit strange, seems very straight forward, trying to split the array by ",", yet i am sure I'm working on a string:

Comment: No, you have an NSArray which you erroneously stuck into an NSString pointer.  It will NSLog as I described.  Assign it to an NSArray and index it and you will see.  Or do `NSLog(@"Class name is %s", object_getClassName(image));`.

Comment: `[__NSArrayI componentsSeparatedByString:]` is telling you you have an array, not a string.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I'm trying to mark this as solved. But check mark does not appear.

Comment: You can't mark a comment as a solution.  If you wish, enter your own answer, explaining what you found, and, after a required waiting period, mark it answered.

Comment: Solved. Was trying to to force an array as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Hot Licks. Just because I say it's a NSTRING means zilch. I am really returning an array.